# Finding Positions of Repeating Elements in a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector `A = [ 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 ]`.

I want to find the positions of every element and store this in its own matrix.

To be more specific, I want to find the position of every elements for each set of elements, in a n by m matrix (where m would be the type of element, and n would be the number of elements found in vector A).

So, for example, assuming there are only values 1, 2, and 3 in vector A, the first column of my matrix would be for values that are 1, and would read off (1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13) and the second column, for values of 2, would read off (4, 8, 9)  and the third column, for values of 3, would read off (5, 6, 7, 14, 15, 16).

Comment: Every row and column in a matrix should have the same length. Your columns don't. Do you want to fill the rest of the matrix with zeros/NaN's or use a cell array for each column?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking of that, a cell array, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

This one liner works as expected:

```
B = accumarray(A', 1:length(A), [], @(x) {sort(x)})
```

`B` is a cell array where `B{i}` contains the sorted list of indices where `i` is located.

Comment: `accumarray` is a fantastic function, I recommend [you read its documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Basically it feeds the indices of all elements equal to `i` as a vector `x` into the function `@(x) {sort(x)}` an assigns the result at position `i` in `B`.

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach -

```
%// For each element create a pair: [R,C], where the first element R would
%// represent its index position in input array and C would be their uniqueness 
[R,C] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),unique(A(:).'))) %//'

%// Find lengths of each unique group
lens = diff([0 ; find(diff(C)) ; numel(C)])

%// Store each element into groups based on the uniqueness and whose
%// values would be the index positions i.e. taken from R
out = mat2cell(R(:).',1,lens)
```

Sample run for given input -

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     1     2     3     3     3     2     2    ...
                            1     1     1     1     3     3     3
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     1     2     3    10    11    12    13
out{2} =
     4     8     9
out{3} =
     5     6     7    14    15    16
```

Comment: Nice +1 :) BTW, may be could have used `[C,R] = sort(A);` ?

Comment: @SanthanSalai Nice! You know you should post that as a solution, because it could be really efficient one!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29934015/2111163) but with `sort`

```
[out,i] = sort(A);
out1 = diff(find([1,diff(out)]));
out2 = [out1,numel(A)-sum(out1(:))];
out3 = mat2cell(i,1,out2);
```

**Results:**

```
A = [ 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 ]; %// input

>> celldisp(out3)

out3{1} =

 1     2     3    10    11    12    13


out3{2} =

 4     8     9


out3{3} =

 5     6     7    14    15    16
```